# Enter key is not doing what it's supposed to on a subform, ideas?

Tags: delphi

I'm calling the subform with the following command:

```
var frm: TForm2;
begin
 try
  frm := TForm2.Create(Application);
  frm.ShowModal;
 finally
  frm.Free;
 end;
end;
```

There's a Rich Edit inside that subform, however, when I press [enter] it acts as a Tab key and switches focus (This is true to all subforms I create inside this particular application, nothing to do with RichEdit itself).

**Notes**: I tried RichEdit.WantReturns true/false, RichEdit.WanTabs true/false, and KeyPreview true/false on the main and subform.

**My thoughts**: The main form does not have any onkey events at all, the ancestor forms does have but nothing to do with [enter]. Since the code is gigantic there might be a place somewhere specifying enter to act as tab, however that'd be too difficult to find. So I just figured if there is a way to make enter act like enter it'd be easier.

Any ideas?

Thank you !

**EDIT**

I found the problem buried deep within a remote .pas file.

```
if Msg.wParam = 13 then
begin
//bunch of code
Msg.wParam := 9; //Ta-da
```

**Thank you** everyone for the support.

Comment: It is not useful to have enter act like tab. Enter means "accept dialog". Tab means "move to next control". You have intentionally modified the default behaviour and now ask us how to undo that modification. But you have not even told us how you have effected the behaviour modification.

Comment: I have not modified the behavior, I haven't developed the application, it's been in development for over 10 years, I've been working on it for less than 6 months and still haven't grasped everything on it.

Comment: Then ask the original developers rather than us!

Comment: Original developers are gone, that's why I asked here. Well, thank you for the effort guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to say what the problem is based on this information.

I'd debug this by setting Debug DCUs to True, setting a breakpoint on `TWinControl.SelectNext` and trying to work out why it lands there when ENTER is pressed.

Comment: But since it's useful to have enter act like tab on other dialogs I was thinking of a way to make this rich edit an exception, then it occurred to me, force richedit.lines.add a new line onKeyDown ? However, still unsure how to make it add a new line :(

Comment: @Rosenberg are you seriously thinking of adding yet more hacks on top of the existing ones?

Comment: @Rosenberg - Just try what David suggested, this should lead you to the problem. You can have a look at the CallStack to find out which method called it.

Comment: David, I'm trying your method, but it's not getting many places. It only shows standard controls on the callstacks when I press ENTER, perhaps I'm doing the breakpoint wrong. I'm setting to breakpoint in the first line after **begin** of TWincontrol.SelectNext

Comment: does it break in SelectNext when you press enter?

Comment: Maybe someone made a copy of an original Delphi source file, and added the modified file to the project, that would explain the strange behavier. Search your *.dpr file for such libraries like "Controls.pas", "ComCtrls.pas" or "StdCtrls.pas" which are not in the original lib directory of Delphi.

Comment: David, yeah, it breaks there, but the call stack lists standard controls only, I keep stepping into and there are only standard controls.

Comment: @Rosenberg Let's trace backwards. When I press TAB on a form I arrive at SelectNext from TCustomForm.CMDialogKey. Do you? And if so, what does the code look like. Do you see VK_ENTER in the code?

Comment: @Rosenberg It's not the function that get called that is important. It's what's in those functions.

Comment: David, thanks for the prolonged assistance. I have analyzed the code @ CMDialogKey, and looks like a normal delphi 7 Control.pas, I pasted the code [here](http://paste2.org/p/1372396) since it's a bit big.

Comment: Something higher up the chain is intercepting the message and changing CharCode from VK_ENTER into VK_TAB. You task is to work out what piece of code effects that change. My guess is something that handles Application.OnMessage.

Comment: Inside TApplication.IsKeyMsg, on the line that reads `Wnd := GetCapture`, i.e. after the test for it being a key message. See what the key is when you get in there. It's really hard to do this in comments!!!

Comment: David, maybe we can exchange aim or msn? But if you feel like I'd be a bother, then never mind this suggestion.

Comment: I think you are on to it now and I don't do IM

Comment: There's a chat here, not sure how to use it, possible to join there? Anyway, I'm not much farther than I was before. :(

Comment: you're nearly there. Just follow it through and see where charcode gets changed. How about using a data breakpoint?

Comment: Read this: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Add_Address_Breakpoint_or_Add_Data_Breakpoint

Comment: Yeah, I'm not going to find the source like this, I don't even know how to keep a watch specifically on charcode. I'll just try to find a work around, thank you for the extensive help.

Comment: David, finally resolved the issue, found the source of the problems. It was replacing <enter> on a Msg level. Only took me 48 hours, heh. Thanks again!

Comment: It was being called by a custom component, which was being used by the whole project, and was being called at the repository form that was the ancestor of the main form, that's why there was nothing unusual at the main form.

Comment: so it was in the ancestor form's OnKeyDown handler?

Comment: Yeah, and it was named something very trivial, in the end I found it on the call stack by doing a breakpoint on TAplication, otherwise I don't think I would've found it.

Comment: well I'm glad you found it and I hope I helped at least in a small way.

Comment: I'd say in a big way, if weren't you encouraging me and telling me where to place break points I wouldn't have found it, thanks man.

Answer (score 3):

First, any particular reason why you don't follow the idiom

```
frm := TForm2.Create(Self);
try
  frm.ShowModal;
finally
  frm.Free;
end;
```

? This standard code is better because 1) `Free` isn't called if `frm` wasn't successfully created, and (2) the operating system (that is, Windows) knows what form to focus (`Self`) when the dialog box is closed.

Second, do you have a button with `Default := true` on `TForm2`? If so, this button will be 'clicked' when you press Enter (unless the control with keyboard focus does something special -- this is not the case for a `TEdit` but possibly for a `TRichEdit`). If the `TRichEdit` has `WantReturns := true`, however, then the Enter key should just create a new line in the Rich Edit control. This is the normal behaviour.

If pressing Enter in an instance of `TForm2` selects the next control in the dialog (with respect to the tab order properties), then you probably have done something special in `TForm2`. Have you overriden the `WndProc` or `CreateParams` procedure of `TForm2`? If so, please have a look there! Or is there something very odd in `TForm2.OnCreate`?

**Update**

Since you say that there isn't any interesting at all in `TForm2`, my psychic powers tell me that you have added a `TApplicationEvents` to your main form, and you are doing something strange when responding to its `OnMessage` event.

Comment: @Andreas You should not ask the first question. The code as presented by OP is an error and you should state it that way, and explain why it is an error.

Comment: There isn't a button with default := true. I changed it to TForm2.Create(self); however, same thing happens. OnCreate has nothing unusual besides loading query, neither does onshow. The form type is TForm, so no form ancestry here. It works fine if I create it on a new application.

Comment: @Rosenberg Why are you asking us how *you* changed the default behaviour?

Comment: @Rosenberg: No `WndProc`, `CreateParams` or any `message` procedure in `TForm2`?

Comment: What I find most odd is that Form2 is clean as a whistle and behaving how it shouldn't if I create it within this particular application. However, if I make a new project and use the very same form2, it works fine. Isn't it strange? Form2 is set as a dialog, but I don't see how it could affect anything.

Comment: @Rosenberg There's something in your code. There are a million and one ways in which this behaviour could be modified.

Comment: @Andreas Read the question and comments again carefully. OP didn't do this. Previous developers did it, and they did it intentionally. This app is designed so that pressing the Enter key moves focus to the next input control. Go figure!

Answer (score 1):

The error is (probably) not in Form2, because Form2 works normal in a clean project.

That leaves the **mainform** and the **project** file (the file with .dpr).
Post the code of the dpr file *(program1.dpr)* in your question, we'll have a look at it.
Next up the mainform. Obviously that's to much code to paste, so let's have all the references to "Enter" or "Return" in the code.

**Search mainform using Delphi**
Open the mainform (usually Form1) in Delphi,
right click on the form and select `View as text` from the menu.
Sometimes Delphi refuses this (when using frames and such), if it does, skip to section *search mainform using wordpad* below.

**Search mainform using Wordpad**
Open the .DFM file of your mainform *(Usually named unit1.dfm)* in **wordpad**.

**Look for "enter" in your form**
Search for the word "Enter" and "Return" and copy and paste the lines where you find this into your question, along with the first line above that has the word `object` in it.

**Look for "enter" in your mainform.pas *(unit1.pas)***
Search for all lines with VK_Enter and VK_Return and #13 and #10 in then and paste them in your question, along with some context code.

**Other possibilities**
If you're using TMS components *(TAdvEdit etc)* many of them have a property called `ReturnIsTab`, search for that as well and set all of them to `false`.

Hopefully we can help you out.

Comment: The developers of the app intentionally made Enter behave like Tab. OP just can't work out why because the codebase is humungous.

Comment: I get it, feel sorry for him, code is probably in mainform though might also be in some custom component that inherites from TForm, that they use as a new Form class, F*** could be anywhere.

Comment: @Johan More likely to be a global Application.OnMessage handler or something like that.

Comment: 1 Custom components messing with messages -> Look to see what components your stuff is based on, look closely at TForm1 = class(xxx) line if xxx <> TForm.   2. Code in the Form1.CreateForm or Form1.ShowForm or Form1.ActivateForm event handlers that does stuff -> Look at all event handlers in mainform and other forms  3. Properties that effect keyboard handling -> see answer post above.